# медиа запросы мешают друг другу

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Пытался разобраться с медиа запросами, появилась проблема для ширины экрана `425px` все работает, для остальных двух разрешений отключаються некоторые стили, но если убрать все медиа запросы, то для обычного расширения экрана все отлично, а с ними не работают некоторые стили

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url(cuba-logo1.png);
  height: 700px;
  width: 1440px;
  background-position: center;
  background-blend-mode: normal, color;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .back {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1024px;
    background-position: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .back {
    height: 291px;
    width: 425px;
    background-position: bottom center;
  }
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1360px;
  height: 620px;
  border: 2px solid #ecb84c;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .border {
    width: 944px;
    height: 530px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .border {
      width: 375px;
      height: 255px;
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
  }
  .text-container {
    width: 527px;
    height: 227px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .header {
    text-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: white;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .header {
      font-size: 180px;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
    .header {
      font-size: 90px
    }
    .small-text-container {
      margin-top: 644px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .small-text-container {
        margin-top: 545px;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
      .small-text-container {
        margin-top: 260px;
      }
      .small-text {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        line-height: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
        .small-text {
          font-size: 14px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="border">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="header">Cuba</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-text-container">
    <div class="small-text">Explore the world of Casas & Cadillacs</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .border{
        width: 944px;
    height: 530px;
    margin-top:32px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Попробуйте скобки закрыть

Comment: <div class="small-text-container">
  <div class="small-text">Explore the world of Casas & Cadillacs</div>
 </div>
  </div>         вот этот текст остаеться без стилей всеравно

Comment: нашел еще пару мест где не закрыл скобки,огромное спасибо,буду внимательнее